# Why ask for a return value?

Tags: java

Here is the example code, very simple.

```
Public String method_A() throws Exception{
    try{
      //do something here

       return "result";
    }catch(Exception e){
       **handleException(e);**   
    }
}

private void handleException(Exception e) throws Exception{
    log.error("", e);
    throw new Exception();
}
```

The compiler complains that "method_A" doesn't return a value. My understanding that, since in its catch block, method "handleException" always throws exception, so no need to return a value.

Did I miss something here?

Comment: Handle exception != throw exception.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response! Yes, I understand. what I'm trying to say is "handleException" always throws exception, so should the compiler understand that?

Comment: The compiler is aware only of methods with the `throws` declaration, as they might throw an exception. In general, it is an undecidable problem to find out whether a given method will throw an exception or not, so the compiler does not check this, even in cases that looks clear.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `catch` block only executes `if` the `try` block throws an exception. Since this is not the case, no exception will be thrown here.

Independent of that, Java requires you to specify an explicit return value even if you think that all code paths in your function throw an exception. While the compiler would be able to figure it out in easy cases (the C# compiler does this, for example) it is theoretically impossible for a compiler to prove that no non-throwing codepaths exist.

Comment: Thanks for all the responses! well, this is the best one I like. hmm, I would expect Java compiler be a little bit smarter and that's not too much I would say....

Answer (score 1):

Java compiler doesn't know `handleException()` always throws the exception anyway. It just thinks you handle the exception, and not rethrow it. Java compiler doesn't follow the code that deep.

However, you're doing it wrong. You should never silence your exceptions. Please do it this way:

```
public String method_A() throws Exception {
    try {
        // do something here
        return "result";
    } catch(Exception e) {
        handleException(e);
        throw e;
    }
}

private void handleException(Exception e) {
    log.error("", e);
}
```

Or just this unless you use `handleException` in other places:

```
public String method_A() throws Exception {
    try {
        // do something here
        return "result";
    } catch(Exception e) {
        log.error("", e);
        throw e;
    }
}
```

Comment: The `throws` clause is not necessary anymore in the declaration of `handleException`.

Comment: Yes, I understand that it'll work. The reason we have it in a separate private method is that in reality the exception handling is much more complicated and we don't want it to fly everywhere.

Comment: But you still need to rethrow in the catch clause, and not in `handleException`. You can't do it differently.

Comment: If handleException needs to modify the exception before rethrowing it, you could also have it return the exception to be thrown by the calling code block.

Answer (score 1):

Just because you're handling the exception doesn't mean that you're throwing an exception (or, at least, that's how the compiler sees it).

There's a *chance* that your method will not return anything if your `try` block fails, and you're handling the exception externally, so the compilation is going to fail to prevent messy errors.

To answer what I believe to be the crux of your question: the code doesn't compile because the compiler will not step through to your other method to see if it throws an exception *there*. You have to throw the exception from *within your method* for the compiler to "see" it.

Try inlining it instead:

```
public String method_A throws Exception{
    try{
        //do something here
        return "result";
    }catch(Exception e){
        log.error("", e);
        throw e;
    }
}
```

Comment: You just threw away the factorization of exception handling :( Factorization was good to avoid duplicated code.

Comment: @Volune Maybe (it depends on how many times this is going to be done): however, the structure is a bit messy in and of itself, so I was trying to work around that.

Answer (score 0):

Since you're declaring the method as a Public String, this means that Java is expecting you to return a string. If you do not have a return statement or it does not specifically throw an exception, the compiler will not like it. It is not about to look at all of your code to see if the exception is thrown every time or not.

Comment: Your wording is confusing as well. A `return` statement can complete a method invocation but so can a `throw` statement. So, _regardless of what else is inside the method_ is wrong.

Comment: Consider updating your answer.

Answer (score -1):

Compiler complains since it does not see the return at end of method. code within try is scoped. It does not really tell compiler if method will return a value. If code throws exception before return, it will be transferred to catch. Usually, a return null at end of method (after all if, try ends) would make compiler happy. In fact, in eclipse, if you code a method with return type specified, first thing you would notice compiler telling is before you write a single line of code is return value. That is the main reason you need a return value at end of method.

Comment: I still don't see the reason for downvoting. I spent time using my practical experience for problems related to this and I got downvoted.